# Organization form in liferay

Tags: liferay

I'm asking about if I can add some fields to organization create and update in portlet control panel organization 
I have first thing name(required).
I need to add another name for organization Arabic name input and supporting Arabic language(multilingual support).
After that I need to add a friendly portlet for members of organization and administrators 
using Life-ray 6.2 tomcat 7.0.42
help please .
Visit https://www.liferay.com/ regularly!
?

i have tried many links with

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://www.liferay.com/web/manish.gupta/blog/-/blogs/liferay-now-have-34-languages-ootb), Liferay already supports Arabic language, so you may not need to add a new field for your organization name. However, if you still want to add new fields, you can do so by adding custom fields to Organization as explained [here](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/custom-fields-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-17-en). Then create a [jsp-hook](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/overriding-a-jsp) to modify Add/update Organization screen in control panel.

[Here's a good document](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Custom+Attributes+and+JSP+Hooks) of similar exercise as what you want to do.

Comment: thank you very much Rushikesh
what about adding portlet organization for users and administrator

Comment: First of all, did I answer your above question? If yes, can you accept it as answer? Next, please elaborate this question as I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: little bit i need to add a text field in create organization and create user in control panel to add another name in arabic
users and organizations must have two names 

after that i need to add portlet for organizations administrator and users to manage the organization and users